# Change title background color in ExtJS Panel

Tags: css, extjs

I have a two panels whose header I want to be in a different color than the default one provided by Ext JS Theme...

```
items: [{
        title: 'Blacklist',
        style: {
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            backgroundImage: 'none'
        },
        padding: '5 5 5 5',
        cls: 'blackList',
        items: [
            grid
        ]
    }
]
```

But it doesn't work. Also I tried to set CSS property in my `styles.css` but it changes only the part of the title.

```
#panel-1091_header-title-textEl{
    background-color: black !important;
}
```

[image]

Comment: you need delete the catcher to see the changes

Comment: Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**FIDDLE**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2man)

Here's the style:

```
.myCls .x-panel-header-default {
    background-color: green;
}
```

And you define the `cls` in panel properties:

```
cls: 'myCls'
```

Answer (score 2):

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/366l)

Please use header and apply style to it:

```
title: 'Blacklist',
header: {
    style: {
        backgroundColor: 'red'
    }
},
```

Do not need to use cls